# trouble with php include and file paths

Tags: php, css

I have a question related to php include. 
I have a folder called login and another folder files. I have a footer.php in files and its stylesheet lies also in same folder as style.css.
so , I want to include footer.php in login.php as `<?php include('../files/footer.php');?>` but its css is missing. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you check in browser that what path it gives while giving `not found` error?

Answer (score 0):

You make your login.php extend some layout.php that has all the required CSS files attached.

Comment: what actually do you mean? what should layout.php include?

Comment: I don't actually know the structure of your project specifically, but it would make sense to separate your main (reusable) template from the others. Like in that layout.php you have your meta tags, CSS, JS etc. and in your login.php you start with something like `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templates/layout.php');`

Answer (score 0):

When you write your html code, use the complete url (start with `http://`) to your css and js file in the `<head>`. This way you will not have problems about relative paths

Answer (score 0):

In the head, you should use an absolute path for your css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/your-main-folder/files/footer.css" />
```

or you can use this:

```
<base href="http://localhost/your-main-folder/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/footer.css" />
```

Comment: [`<base>` doesn't require HTML5?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)